# How to convert a numpy array of dimension (x,y,z) to (x,y,z-1)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimesion (1471,6,4) and I would like to convert it into (1471,6,3)

Answer (score 0):

If by "convert" you mean reshape, you can't, since your new array has less elements than the original one.

But you can basically skip the last channel and only take the first three ones.

`new_array = old_array[:,:,:3]`

If you don't need the old array, you can just overwrite it.
It will look as it has been "converted" to the new shape (but you will loose the 4th channel data)

`my_array = my_array[:,:,:3]`